# "NOT EXISTS" in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm stuck on a simple problem in prolog.
Let's consider the program

```
worker(bill).
worker(smitt).
worker(fred).
worker(dany).
worker(john).
car(bmw).
car(mazda).
car(audi).
owner(fred,mazda).
owner(dany,bmw).
owner(john,audi).
```

I need to add one more predicate no_car(X),that will be true if the worker X has no cars,i.e,if we input a query 
?:- no_car(X).
the prolog should answer

```
X=smitt,
X=bill,
yes
```

What i have done is

```
   hascar(X):-owner(X,_).
   nocar(X):- worker(X),not hascar(X).
```

But this approach does not work because anonimous variables are avaliable only for queries.
So,i'm really stuck on this.
I know there are "NOT EXISTS" words in SQL which allow to express this logic in a query,but is there something similar to them in prolog?

Comment: your code works if you use \+ instead of not, it has nothing to do with anonymous variables..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me and provides the expected result:

```
no_car(W):-
   worker(W),
   \+ owner(W, _).
```

Now this is close to what you have. For one thing, you *can* of course use `_` in predicates; it is not restricted to queries. I usually use `\*` for negation, and `not` gives me a syntax error here!?

EDIT:

Ah! In my, albeit dated, version of Prolog you have to use `not(hascar(X))` to make it work, so not/1 needs to be used as a term, not an operator. But the manual also says `not` is deprecated in favor of `\+`.

Comment: Thank you! not(hascar(X)) works fine. Looks strange after working with some other versions of prolog, i didn't guess to check it.